# Setting timeout for an async operation

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm using a nuget package that allows interaction with `UptimeRobot` monitoring service. Unfortunately this package doesn't seem to have a timeout set when using the service therefore the `awaitable` task goes forever. So I need to do it myself.

And I came up with this:

```
List<Monitor> monitors = null;

int timeOut = 8000; // 8 seconds
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew (async () => await _client.GetMonitors ());

if(!task.Wait (timeOut))
{
    throw new Exception ();
}
else
{
    monitors = await task.Result;
}
```

It seems like it should work but it never throws that exception. Why?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155760.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: On a side note, you [should use `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).